# Searching for QtConurrent substitution (map-reduce)

Tags: c++, qt, mapreduce

I heavily used Qt concurrent in my projects, until recently [found](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-3786) that is does not work.

So, is there any substitution?

I'm especially interested in map-reduce concept implementation. I've looked through `boost::mapreduce`, but it seems overcomplicated. I mean, with Qt I could just start task with

```
QtConcurrent::mappedReduced<map_result>(begin, end, mapfunction_or_function, reducefunction_or_functor)
```

and I could even use lamdas for functors. With boost I have to create own classes for map task and reduce task.